# Desktop Icon's cannot be moved & Scrolling in excel does not work

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I have a domain user running Windows 7 Pro and he is having an issue where his icons on his desktop get stuck and cannot be moved (Auto Arrange is unchecked). What's even more weird is when he is having this issue he also suddenly cannot use the mouse scroll button on any excel sheets. Even when I remotely connect to his computer I am still unable to scroll in excel or move his desktop icons.

Most of the time simply doing a Ctrl + Alt + Del and pressing cancel right away will temporarily resolve the issue. When that doesn't work we need to reboot the computer in safe mode, login and then reboot the computer in normal mode to resolve the issue for 1-2 days.

I've been as far as actually reinstalled the operating system however a couple days later it came back. Many people are pointing me towards the GPO's on the AD server however this is the only user part of his group who is experiencing this issue. When I examined the GPO's they are only for disabling the firewall and enabling remote desktop.

I've spent many hours on this issue and have come out clueless (even with google). I'm hoping someone could give me a hand before I go crazy and get another kitten!

The AD server is running on windows server 2003

Comment: Maybe a strange question but: Do you have [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) installed?

Comment: @nixda No VMware is installed.